# Why does the Keras sequence-to-sequence tutorial not mention the TimeDistributed layer wrapper?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The [Keras sequence to sequence tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) explains the implementation of a sequence-to-sequence RNN, without even mentioning the usage of a [TimeDistributed layer wrapper](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed).  [The accepted answer to another question in stackoverflow](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/the-difference-between-dense-and-timedistributeddense-of-keras) seems to imply however, that the usage of a TimeDistributed layer is indispensable to separate the individual time steps in the Dense layer (which seems logical to me).

So why is the TimeDistributed layer wrapper not even mentioned in the Keras tutorial? To keep things simple? Or does the tutorial use an architecture which doesn't require TimeDistributed? Or is it based on a Keras version that does not include or require TimeDistributed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `Dense` layer, it's absolutely optional and it makes no difference.

The (current) behavior for Dense layers is to act on the last dimension and leave the others untouched. (In previous versions, like keras 1, this wasn't true and you actually needed the `TimeDistributed` wrapper).

So, if you input `(samples, steps, input_dimension)` into a `Dense` layer, you will get the output `(samples, steps, units_or_output_dimension)`, which is exactly the same thing that a `TimeDistributed(Dense(...))` would do.

For other layers, the use of `TimeDistributed` may be necessary, indeed. For instance, when you're processing movies in convolutional networks, you may want 2D convolutions with an input shape of `(samples, frames, imageWidth, imageHeight, channels)`, and then you will need the `TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...))` in order to have the additional `frames` dimension.

Comment: Does that mean the Keras tutorial is based on a Keras version which already implements the behavior which the quoted stackoverflow answer explicitely "implements"?  I am trying to understand the apparent contradiction between the tutorial and the stackoverflow answer.

Comment: There is no contradiction. `Dense` and `TimeDistributed(Dense(...))` in Keras 2 do exactly the same thing --- That answer is just explaining what `TimeDistributed` does (with all layers, not just with Dense), but this is a feature that a `Dense` layer already has by itself.

Comment: Make this simple test: create two models, same size, one of them using `TimeDistributed` and the other just `Dense`. Copy the weights from one to the other: `model1.set_weights(model2.get_weights())`. Then make a `model.predict(someInput)` and see them output the same result.